# Rotating an image, angle by angle, and waiting for refresh

Tags: android, multithreading, view, rotation, runnable

I'm trying to rotate an image a full rotation, a small angle-increment at a time.

Each proceeding rotation should begin after the previous rotation has been displayed.

How fast the rotation happens means nothing to me - as long as each rotation is displayed it's fine by me. That means it can be practically considered to be "too fast".

I've tried a few different approaches for this. I have a working solution below (something along these lines, at least - I've been playing with the code, so it might not be completely compilable).

`handler` is a Handler instance and is together with all of the code below located in the body of the activity class that I'm starting from. `rotationIncrement` is 0.36, so we're "rotating" the image 1000 times by posting a new Runnable to the UI-thread each time the previous rotation is finished.

```
public void start(View view) {
    MainActivity.rotation=0;
    imageview.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
    handler.post(new RotationRunnable());       
}

public class RotationRunnable implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            MainActivity.rotation+=rotationIncrement;
            //Log.d("Rotating", String.valueOf(rotation));
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix(imageview.getImageMatrix());
            matrix.setRotate(rotation);
            imageview.setImageMatrix(matrix);
            imageview.invalidate();

            if (MainActivity.rotation<360) {
                handler.post(new RotationRunnable());
            } else {
                Log.d("Elapsed", String.valueOf((System.nanoTime()-startTime)));
            }
        }
}
```

The code above gives me a pretty smooth "animation". With a 1000 rotations, it takes about 16s on my Samsung Galaxy Nexus to finish.

My question is this;

**Is there a better way to do this - if the goal is to have the rotation happen as fast as possible - and maintaining that each rotation is displayed in order?**

This is NOT going to be implemented into a product or anything - this is more an artificial test, so I'm not looking for any more "convenient" ways of animating a rotation.

Comment: That is pretty much the fastest you are going to get. The quickest refresh you can get is one frame to another frame. Assuming 60 frames per second. 1000/60 = 16.67 seconds. Unless you find a way to crank up the frame rate (which I doubt) or reduce the number of rotations, its not going to be possible to reduce the time. If you 1 deg each rotation, that gives you 6 seconds.

Comment: I'm unsure how you can not care about the speed-  is it being shown on screen?  If so, you ned it to be slow enough for the user to see it.  If not, you can rotate it and draw to a bitmap rather than the screen and that will be orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: @Aswin, that's something I did not think about, thank you. Two follow up questions; 1) Might be a silly question but; consider a future generation of phones could handle 600 frames per second. Is there a way to test for that scenario? 2) Is there an easy way to make the computation more intensive to make the framerate drop significantly?

Comment: @Poyan You can test it by doing the same method above for one second and see how many iterations you went through to find out the frame rate. Once you find out the fps, you can make better guess on the computation time. There are many ways to limit the frame rate to a certain number to make computation more predictable. One way is what is commonly used in games. You can search for android game loop mechanism which controls the frame rate. Check out one of the tutorials here (http://www.koonsolo.com/news/dewitters-gameloop/).